# Is it possible to migrate history from TFVC repository to a Git repository AFTER the code has already moved?

Tags: git, migration, git-history

Last year the code from a TFS TFVC repository was copied to a TFS Git repository without History. It was just a copy/paste of the files into the new git repository. Is it possible to now migrate the history from the old TFVC repository?

Answer (score 0):

That is possible but it depends what are your expectations.

What you have to do:

1. Migrate the history in a new git repository (not an easy task but I will take granted that you succeed at doing it)
2. Add this new repository as a remote in a repository containing already the newest history (`git remote add ...`) and `git fetch --all`
3. Create a local branch(es) on the last commits and push it to your central repository.
4. You will now have to play with `git replace --graft` to link the old history with the new one.

From doc:

> `git replace --graft <commit> [<parent>…​]`
>
> Create a graft commit. A new commit is created with the same content as  except that its parents will be […​] instead of 's parents.

So run the command:

`git replace --graft <sha1_first_commit_new_history> <sha1_last_commit_old_history>`

Here, you have 2 options:

- run this command in all the already existing repositories and run this command every times you clone the repository.
- make the graft permanent but with the downside that all the sha1 of the new history will change. You have to see if it's acceptable for you.

If it is do :

1. `git filter-branch -- --all` to make it permanent (verify after that the result and delete the filter-branch backup branches if all is well)
2. `git push --force -- --all` (will update the central remote repository)